# OS listdir not reading certain files

Tags: python, operating-system, listdir

I'm trying to access a folder and read the text files in it. Eventually I'm going to build them into a basic dictionary to dump into JSON but something's going on with the files. I'm getting an error message:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: ___
```

The thing is, this code IS working on my test files ... so maybe it's somehow a file issue?

```
import json
import os

for file in os.listdir("filepath"):
    with open ('%s.json' % file, 'w') as fp:
        file = f.read()
        f = open(file, 'r')
        print (f)
```

These are the text files not getting 'found/read':
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B4zJC6biI6jERDFHSzZvUUJaRE0

Has anyone else run into this problem / found a solution that might work?

Comment: Neither of the files at your external link have a `.json` extension they are both `.txt` files and thus the open fails.

Comment: is every file inside the `filepath` directory of the extension `.jsoin`?

Comment: That section of the code just is related to later on when I want to write results of the open/read files to a json file. Even with that line commented out the files aren't being read.

Comment: `os.listdir()` does not include the path.  You need `with open(os.path.join('filepath', '%s.json' % file, 'w') as fp:`

Comment: MY test files were also text and reading just fine. Those docs are here: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B4zJC6biI6jEYmw4YS1rd3dDSlE